# Group by using local storage in HTML5

Tags: html, local-storage

I am creating my first mobile application using HTML5 and JqueryMobile. Storing all datas in localstorage. Anyone can suggest me the easy way to retrieve grouped data count from following resultset,

```
1 mango
2 orange
3 mango
4 apple
5 mango
6 apple
7 orange
8 orange
9 apple
10 mango
```

Expected result

```
 mango  4
 orange 3
 apple  3
```

Comment: where you are storing your data? in local browser database or somewhere else

Comment: How do you store the data? The answer depends on how you push the data in the storage.

Answer (score 0):

you can do the same using query lik

```
SELECT Fruit_Name, COUNT(*) as "Fruit Count"
FROM Fruits
GROUP BY Fruit_Name;
```

Selecting data and rendering in HTML5 is [explained here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webdatabase/todo/).

Comment: in your question you have mentioned it.

Comment: *This is not my question.* You've shown the solution using a deprecated method ([WebSQL](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/)). [`localStorage`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/local-storage) is a different API.